# How to make a macro to save .txt files as .xls files on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently get a lot of .txt files from XSENS sensors that we use that I want to convert into xls files so that MATLAB can read an organized file.

These converted .xls files have tens of columns and thousands of rows of data. I attempted to make a macro for this so that I don't have the button click everything but it is not working.

```
Function GetFullNameXLS() As String
GetFullNameXLS = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".txt", ".xlsx")
End Function

Sub XLSB()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Type:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, filename:= _
    GetFullNameXLS
End Sub
```

Currently a VBA rookie so any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot just rename a file and have it magically become a different type of file.  Are they really text files, or are they really Excel files that are named incorrectly?  If they just need to be renamed this is better accomplished on the command line or with a batch file.  Please clarify.

Comment: How are the text files formatted?  Are they tab delimited?  comma delimited?  some other delimiter?